# psqlodbca.so: Unable to open shared object file: File or directory not found

Tags: postgresql, migration, mysql-workbench

I can not migrate the PostegreSql database to mysql because of this error:

psqlodbca.so: Unable to open shared object file: File or directory not found

I'm using ubuntu 64 Postgresql 9x and 6.6 workbench

how should I proceed ??

[image: bug]

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as root to install dependency:

```
apt install odbc-postgresql-dbg
```